# How can I detect if ListView item added off-screen?

Tags: flutter, dart, flutter-listview

How can I detect if a ListView item was added off-screen?  I would like to scroll to the newly added item if it was added off-screen.

Below is a minimal example.  If you keep pressing the + button, eventually an item will be added off-screen.  I would like to detect that case and then scroll to the newly added item.

```
class _MyHomePageState extends State<MyHomePage> {
  List<String> _items = [];

  void _addItem() {
    final count = _items.length + 1;

    setState(() {
      _items.add('Item $count');
    });
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(
        title: Text(widget.title),
      ),
      body: ListView.builder(
          itemCount: _items.length,
          itemBuilder: (_, index) {
            return Container(
              height: 50,
              child: Card(
                child: Row(
                  mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.spaceAround,
                  children: <Widget>[
                    Text(_items[index]),
                  ],
                ),
              ),
            );
          }),
      floatingActionButton: FloatingActionButton(
        onPressed: _addItem,
        tooltip: 'Add Item',
        child: Icon(Icons.add),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

https://dartpad.dev/81dcfd6e4255bde548751180c54a9ade

Check this.
You need to use a scroll controller

## Update

Here is the code as the above Dartpad link is not working:

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

void main() {
  runApp(MyApp());
}

class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
      debugShowCheckedModeBanner: false,
      home: Scaffold(
        body: MyHomePage()
      ),
    );
  }
}

class MyHomePage extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  createState() => _MyHomePageState();
}

class _MyHomePageState extends State<MyHomePage> {
  List<String> _items = [];
  
  // Add a scroll controller
  ScrollController _scrollController = ScrollController();

  void _addItem() {
    final count = _items.length + 1;
    
    setState(() {
      _items.add('Item $count');
    });
    
    // Wait a frame for the new item to be built in your list view
    WidgetsBinding.instance.addPostFrameCallback((duration) {
       if(_scrollController.hasClients) {
         // Move to the maxScrollExtent once the item has been added
        _scrollController.animateTo(
        _scrollController.position.maxScrollExtent,
        curve: Curves.easeIn, // Use any curve you like
        duration: const Duration(milliseconds: 200) // Set the anim duration
       );
      }
    });
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(
        title: Text('Demo'),
      ),
      body: ListView.builder(
          controller: _scrollController, // Assign the controller
          itemCount: _items.length,
          itemBuilder: (_, index) {
            return Container(
              height: 50,
              child: Card(
                child: Row(
                  mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.spaceAround,
                  children: <Widget>[
                    Text(_items[index]),
                  ],
                ),
              ),
            );
          }),
      floatingActionButton: FloatingActionButton(
        onPressed: _addItem,
        tooltip: 'Add Item',
        child: Icon(Icons.add),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

Comment: Perfect!  Thanks.

Comment: The link is gone. You should put your answer here instead of just providing a link.